# Workbook issue implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.0.0'

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying fileupload using srpingboot version 2.5.4.

here are the other dependencies:

```
implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: '1.20'
```

The  file upload works perfectly fine on local ubuntu however while running on docker [FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine3.9] I am getting bellow error:

======================

```
java.io.IOException: Truncated ZIP file
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.readStored(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:559)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.read(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:486)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.read(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:80)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:183)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:150)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveFakeEntry.<init>(ZipArchiveFakeEntry.java:47)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:53)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:106)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:312)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:295)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:163)
    at com.pitstop.catalogue.service.BulkUploadService.validateNUpload(BulkUploadService.java:390)
    at com.pitstop.catalogue.service.BulkUploadService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2055c6e6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.pitstop.catalogue.service.BulkUploadService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ea4b4b20.validateNUpload(<generated>)
    at com.pitstop.catalogue.web.rest.BulkUploadResource.productUpload(BulkUploadResource.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
```

Comment: It might not be a jdk or jre docker image issue as I tested with open JDK image as well.

Comment: Have you considered the possiblilty that you have a 'Truncated ZIP file' as the error message says?